# extracting number from string of number in specific order

Tags: c, arrays, string, image

Need to extract number from a string and save it to an array.
string pattern used is pixel value pattern of an image.
we need to convert the image to gray scale so need to extract this values
also need help for coverting image pixel values to grayscale image pixel values

`

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<string.h>
  main()
  {
  char *arr[2] = { "(98, 23, 56)", "(218, 176, 164)" };
  char c[100];
  c[0]=0;
   int state,i,j,digit[2][3],k=0,m=0;
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
  for(j=0;arr[i][j]!='\0';j++)
  { 
   switch(arr[i][j])

  case '(':     printf("hello\n");  
         j++;
        int no=0;
        while(arr[i][j]!=',')
        {
        c[0]=arr[i][j];
        no=(no*10)+c[0];
        j++;
        }
        printf("\nendofcase1%c",&no);
        digit[k][m]=no;
        m++;
        break;
        case ',':
                    no=0;
                    j++;

                j++;
                while(arr[i][j]!=',')
                 {
                 c[0]=arr[i][j];
                 no=(no*10)+c[0];
                 j++;
                 }
                printf("\nendofcase2%c",no);
                digit[k][m]=no;
                m++;
                break;  
                }

              }
              k++;
         }
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
         {
          for(j=0;j<3;j++)
           {
            printf("array of values:%d",&digit[i][j]);
           }
           printf("\n");
         } 

    }`
```

Comment: What is the issue??What is the error??

Comment: I tried to format your code but finally gave up. This will not even compile.

Comment: Please reformat and indent your code. Why don't use the available strtok or any other string tokenized library?

Comment: You have loops (`while`) inside loops (`for`) and changes to the control variable throughout all of that. Do yourself a favour and clean your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *arr[2] = { "(98, 23, 56)", "(218, 176, 164)" };
    int i,j, digit[2][3];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        sscanf(arr[i], "(%d, %d, %d", &digit[i][0],&digit[i][1], &digit[i][2]);

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("array of values:%d ", digit[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key issue was 2 lines which should have been

```
// no=(no*10)+c[0];
no = (no*10) + c[0] - '0';
```

Re-wrote and created `ParseRGB()`.  However the string is parsed, suggest it gets its own function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int ParseRGB(int digit[3], const char *arr) {
  int ch;
  char sep = '(';
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (*arr++ != sep) return 1;
    sep = ',';
    while (*arr == ' ') arr++;
    if ((ch = *arr++) < '0' || ch > '9') return 1;
    digit[i] = ch - '0';
    while ((ch = *arr) >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
      digit[i] = digit[i]*10 + ch - '0';
      arr++;
    }
  }
  if  (ch != ')') return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  const char *arr[2] = { "(98, 23, 56)", "(218, 176, 164)" };
  int i;
  int digit[2][3];
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (ParseRGB(digit[i], arr[i])) {
      printf("Error in '%s'\n", arr[i]);
    }
    else {
      printf("array of values:(%d, %d, %d)\n",
         digit[i][0], digit[i][1], digit[i][2]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```